# awk deduct column value if column value are equal

Tags: awk, addition

i ve a input file which i'd like to deduct the column value if the those column value are equal.

> INPUT FILE:

```
0823 182331.58 5693
0823 182332.23 5693
0823 182331.52 5694
0823 182341.12 5694
0823 182332.99 5695
```

*182332.23 - 182331.58

***182341.12 - 182331.52

my expected output is:

```
0823 0.65 5693
0823 9.6 5694
```

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
awk '$3 in saved{$2 = $2 - saved[$3]; print} {saved[$3] = $2}' file
```

Comment: thx! it works fine but i found something wried. Since my input file is more than 10000 line and i found that the result mess up starting from line 10000. is it a limitation in awk?

Comment: No, that is a relatively small file. There's something you don't understand about your input file (control characters? format change? other?) so you'll have to investigate that and come back if you need help solving the problem after you figure out what the problem with your input file is.